# Python ‘numpy.ndarray’ object is not callable Solution

Tags: python, numpy, regression, linear-regression, numpy-ndarray

I'm doing a simple linear regression task for predicting house prices, using RMSE, with the following code

```
# A function that take one input of the dataset and return the RMSE (of the test data), and the intercept and coefficient
def simple_linear_model(train, test, input_feature):
    regr = linear_model.LinearRegression() # Create a linear regression object
    regr.fit(train.values(columns = [input_feature]), train.as_matrix(columns = ['Price'])) # Train the model
    RMSE = mean_squared_error(test.values(columns = ['Price']), 
                              regr.predict(test.values(columns = [input_feature])))**0.5 # Calculate the RMSE on test data
    return RMSE, regr.intercept_[0], regr.coef_[0][0]

input_list = data.columns.values.tolist() # list of column name
input_list.remove('Price')
simple_linear_result = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['feature', 'RMSE', 'intercept', 'coefficient'])

# loop that calculate the RMSE of the test data for each input 

for p in input_list:
    RMSE, w1, w0 = simple_linear_model(train_data, test_data, p)
    simple_linear_result = simple_linear_result.append({'feature':p, 'RMSE':RMSE, 'intercept':w0, 'coefficient': w1}
                                                       ,ignore_index=True)
simple_linear_result.sort_values('RMSE').head(10) # display the 10 best estimators
```

This error is coming:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [12], in <cell line: 6>()
      5 # loop that calculate the RMSE of the test data for each input 
      6 for p in input_list:
----> 7     RMSE, w1, w0 = simple_linear_model(train_data, test_data, p)
      8     simple_linear_result = simple_linear_result.append({'feature':p, 'RMSE':RMSE, 'intercept':w0, 'coefficient': w1}
      9                                                        ,ignore_index=True)
     10 simple_linear_result.sort_values('RMSE').head(10)

Input In [11], in simple_linear_model(train, test, input_feature)
      2 def simple_linear_model(train, test, input_feature):
      3     regr = linear_model.LinearRegression() # Create a linear regression object
----> 4     regr.fit(train.values(columns = [input_feature]), train.as_matrix(columns = ['Price'])) # Train the model
      5     RMSE = mean_squared_error(test.values(columns = ['Price']), 
      6                               regr.predict(test.values(columns = [input_feature])))**0.5 # Calculate the RMSE on test data
      7     return RMSE, regr.intercept_[0], regr.coef_[0][0]

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Not sure which part is coming out to be an array honestly.

Comment: From the name, I'd suspect this: `as_matrix(...` : if as_matrix indeed is a np-array, calling it as a function (with () instead of []) would yield this error.

Comment: @Swifty Thanks for your comment, i amended it to .values() and still get the same error

Comment: What are the types of both `train.values` and `train.as_matrix`?

Comment: `train.values(columns = [input_feature])` treats `train.values` as a function, a `callable`.  Usually we use `values` to get numpy array from a dataframe or series. An array is not callable.